# Fill numpy matrix with values from an index to another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is about filling a numpy matrix with values from an index to another.

For example I have this matrix :

```
> mat = np.zeros((0,5))

> mat
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
```

For example, Let's say I want to fill mat from row 1 to 3 at the first column with value : 1 so it will look like this :

```
> mat
  0 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
```

Here's what I have tried but here 1 is applied to all the columns instead of one column :

```
mat[1:3][1]=1
```

What's the problem here ?

Comment: Look at mat[1:3] and mat[1:3][1].  Seems, you want 
`mat[1:4,0]=1`

Comment: Think that arrays starts at position 0 and not 1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

first of all, you don't create the desired matrix. `np.zeros((0,5))` will not work. You should try `mat = np.zeros((5,5))` instead.

The other issue is accessing created matrix. To access 0th elements of rows from 1 inclusive to 3 inclusive you need to call:

```
mat[1:4,0]=1
```

Answer (score 2):

`mat = np.zeros((0,5))` is not creating matrix that u need.
The right way is

`mat = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=int)`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
mat[1:4, 0] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`mat[1:3][1]` is a list. You don't want to replace it with integer value.

Use

```
for list_ in mat[1:4]:
    list_[0]=1
```